# Can't make the lc parameter work?

Tags: powershell, if-statement, case-insensitive, uppercase, lowercase

I'm trying to create a simple `if` statement and want it to ignore case.

This is my pseudo code:

```
if (Lowercase $xxx notequal lowercase "xxx")
{......}
```

I've tried:

```
if ( -lc $ConfigAppUsers  -ne -lc "No"  )
if (  lc $ConfigAppUsers  -ne  lc "No"  )
if (( lc $ConfigAppUsers) -ne (lc "No") )
if ((-lc $ConfigAppUsers) -ne (-lc "No"))
```

and I always get:

```
-lc : The term '-lc' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a
path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ -lc "No"
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-lc:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `lc 'Perl' ne lc 'shell script'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lc` is a Perl function, not a PowerShell function. In PowerShell you can lowercase a string by calling the `ToLower()` method of the string object:

```
if ($ConfigAppUsers.ToLower() -ne 'no')
```

However, PowerShell comparisons are case-insensitive by default, so you don't actually need this. Simply comparing the strings will suffice:

```
if ($ConfigAppUsers -ne 'No')
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why you keep adding minus signs:

```
if ( lc $ConfigAppUsers ne "no" ) {
  ...
}
```

You could say `lc "No"` instead of `"no"`, but it's kind of silly to be calling `lc` on a string literal.

Your other problem appears to be that you aren't using Perl.  The error you're getting is not a Perl error message.  I think it's a Windows PowerShell error.

Comment: S#$%,  i'm sorry , i got confused, i'm working on too many things at the same time. i ment PowerShell, Fixed the question.